# How to connect to a MySQL database on another domain?

Tags: php, mysql

Basically, I need to connect to another database on a different domain.

For example, I'll use `domain1` and the domain that needs to connect, and `domain2` as the domain that has the database.

I have tried:

```
mysql_connect("domain2.com.au", "user", "pass") or die(mysql_error());

mysql_select_db("database") or die(mysql_error());
```

Although, that refused to work.

I looked for quite some time online to find a solution, and many of them involved logging into `SSH` which I am not familiar with and I would like to avoid this method.

---

If needed, here is my error (some things modified for privacy):

```
Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: Access denied for user 'user'@'host.com' (using password: YES) in /php/2012.php on line 270
Access denied for user 'user'@'host.com' (using password: YES)
```

---

Is there an option that I must change within my database to allow access from other domains? If so, where exactly is this?

Is there a port that I need to connect to such as `domain2.com.au:3307`?

Comment: It really should work. Check with your hosting provider if they block remote MySQL connections.

Comment: Are you hosting these servers yourself or do you have a web host? Most hosts probably block access to MySQL from outside IPs, meaning you can't do what you want without them opening ports.

Comment: **use mysqli or PDO instead mysql_* functions**

Comment: The domain that I am trying to connect to is hosted with a company, and the domain that is doing the connecting is hosted with a separate company. None of these are localhost.

Comment: I would use `new mysqli()`, and the Object Oriented approach.

Comment: @CollinGrady - Would it be possible for me to maybe call them and get them to open this port?

Comment: @PHPglue - Honestly, I'm super new to MySQL and I have absolutely no idea how to do that haha.

Comment: That's not MySQL it's still PHP. See the examples here: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php

Comment: @PHPglue - Do you think this method could eliminate the problem I am having?

Comment: See @edditor' answer, you need to grant cross-domain permissions. (GRANT ALL...). It then should work for you.

Comment: I tried the following: `GRANT ALL ON db_name.* TO dbuser_name@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'user_pass';` Although it returned an error of `#1044 - Access denied for user 'dbuser'@'localhost' to database 'db_name'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using shared hosting, then it's disabled. You could try enabling it by contacting your support department, or if you have cPanel x3 go to Remote Database section in your MySQL section.

Comment: Going to `Remote Database` and assigning the wild card there worked perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: Keep in mind that if you suddenly notice slow page load times, thats because database queries sent to the 'outside' server (not localhost) are much slower. And if you have lots of queries, it may slow down page considerably.

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable remote access on `domain2`'s MySQL server.

Open your `my.cnf` file (`/etc/mysql/my.cnf` for debian based linux) and make sure you delete or comment the line:

```
#skip-networking
```

and add or edit this line:

```
bind-address=[YOUR SERVER's EXTERNAL IP]
```

After that restart your mysql service.

```
/etc/init.d/mysql restart
```

or

```
service mysql restart
```

Then you need to grant remote access to the database. Open the mysql console:

```
mysql -u root –p mysql

mysql> GRANT ALL ON [DB].* TO '[USER]'@'[IP]' IDENTIFIED BY '[PASSWORD]';
mysql> exit
```

Where `[DB]` is the database, `[USER]` is the mysql username, `[IP]` is your server's external IP adress and `[PASSWORD]` the user's password.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/grant.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Where abouts is the `my.cnf` file? Is it within `PHPMyAdmin`? I am inside my Cpanel.

Comment: Also, the `PASSWORD` part, is this the password for that database's user?

Comment: Oh sorry, did misread, that you DON'T want to login through SSH. 
But if the config is not already configured for remote access you have to do it. If you have the mysql root user access you can try to execute the query in phpmyadmin.

Comment: Yes PASSWORD is the password.